# Context is not available right after page refresh in React

Tags: reactjs

There's **WarriorPage** component which use context where is data I want to render. After page refresh, firstly I got an empty array from the context and only after a while I got array with my data. That causes error because I'm destructuring object from that array(which is empty in the start). Any sugestions?

**WarriorPage**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import AllWarriorsContext from '../../contexts/AllWariorsContext';

export default function WarriorPage() {

    let { identy } = useParams();
    const { warriorsData } = useContext(AllWarriorsContext);
    const {number, name, skill, description} = warriorsData[identy]; // got undefined here after page reload

    return(...);
}
```

**In Parent component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import AllWarriorsContext from '../../contexts/AllWariorsContext';
import WarriorPage from '../WarriorPage/WarriorPage';

export default function Parent() {
const [myWarriorsListContext, setMyWarriorsListContext] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {

    setMyWarriorsListContext(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myWarriorsList')) || []);
    
},[]);

return(
    <AllWarriorsContext.Provider value={{
        warriorsData: allWarriorsData
    }}>
         <WarriorPage />
    </AllWarriorsContext>

);
}
```

Comment: Where you get `allWarriorsData`? If it's from the server it does make sense that it will take some time. You can render `WarriorPage` conditionally e.g. `{allWarriorsData 
 && <WarriorPage />}`

Comment: I simplified this code, but inside useEffect I'm fetching API data ONLY if it's not avaiable in localstorage. If data is in localstorage, I take that data and then put it to `allWarriorsData`

Comment: `useEffect` is async (you can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-violet-224tu?file=/src/App.js:144-153) so anyway it will be the default value (the value that you put in the `useState`. So you can take the value from the localStorage and put it as a default value.

Comment: `const {number, name, skill, description} = warriorsData[identy] || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identy));` that's how I did it. Thank's Mosh for help with understanding my problem.

Comment: My pleasure :) I'd recommend to put the value in the context first instead of doing in it in the child component so if there is another component (maybe grand children) which need this data you'd have to getting data from the localStorage again.